# How can an ANT build script kill a Windows process?

Tags: windows, ant, command-line, build

I'm working on extending an ANT build script to allow a TeamCity build agent to run Selenium tests.

In doing so there is a server required to start with selenium which isn't shutdown at the end. So I added an extra target to execute a taskkill on the exe name at the end of every TC build.

Does taskkill need the absolute path to the exe, because the following isn't working;

```
<target name="shutdown.server" depends="init.properties" description="Shutdown the server after Selenium">
    <exec osfamily="windows" executable="cmd.exe" spawn="true">
        <arg line="taskkill /f /t /im app.exe"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

The process seems to have a few children which is why I've gone with `/f /t` but as I say, none of them shutdown at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well that was easy;

```
<target name="shutdown.server" depends="init.properties" description="Shutdown the server after Selenium">
    <exec executable="taskkill">
        <arg line="/im app.exe /f /t"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: exec has the property executable? didn't see that in the documentation

Comment: @koo9 I'm not sure the current state of ant, but back in 2013 it was a property, so give it a go & see if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post and normally I use the `timeout="milliseconds"` , but for a long running process, I have found that the best way of killing an *Ant* launched process (especially `java.exe` threads within Eclipse) is to use [pskill.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill).

Just load pskill64.exe into the project directory and run the following *Ant* build.

```
<project name="project" default="shutdown.java.tasks" basedir="../">
<target name="shutdown.java.tasks">

    <exec executable="path.to.pskill.in.your.project\pskill64">
        <arg value="java.exe" />
    </exec>

</target>
```

Typical output is:

```
shutdown.java:
 [exec] PsKill v1.16 - Terminates processes on local or remote systems
 [exec] Copyright (C) 1999-2016  Mark Russinovich
 [exec] Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
 [exec] 8 processes named java.exe killed.
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 387 milliseconds